# Deleting files in optimal way .

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I wondered about this after deleting some of the files on my computer :

> Suppose you have $n^2$ files in a folder , arranged in an $n$ by $n$ square out of which only $n$ are useful and the rest $n^2-n$ are junk . You want to delete the $n^2-n$ junk files while keeping the other $n$ .The $n$ useful files are exactly on the principal diagonal (which connects top-left with bottom-right) . Also (as you may know ) you can select a rectangular block of files by holding the left-click and then deleting them together.
>
> The question is :
>
> What is the most optimal way to delete the junk files while keeping the useful ones .

Note :

1. When you delete some items in a folder the ones that remain will be reorganized (they don't remain in their position )
2. You cannot touch in any way the useful files (ex : move them to other folders ) . You must only delete the junk files .

I found only the obvious way :

Start from the bottom to the top :

- On the last row delete the block $ 1 \times (n-1) $
- On the second to last row delete the blocks $1 \times (n-2)$ and $1 \times 1$

and so on ...

In this way I make $2n-2$ deletes but I think we can do significantly better .

Thanks for your help with this question .

Comment: You can't do any better. All the elements on diagonal $1$ and diagonal $-1$ (diagonal $0$ is the principal one) have to be deleted in separate deletes and there are exactly $2(n-1)$ such elements.

Comment: @A.S. But the files reorganize after each deletion and they will not stay in the same configuration . If this was not the case your argument seems fine .

Comment: Gotcha. I skipped the part addressing this after reading the highlighted part and the sentence before last. Maybe you could include that very important process detail in the highlight (on the other hand, note 2 is obvious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do it in n deletes.  Delete the first column (below the useful file).  Note that the useful files in 2nd - nth rows now are one element closer to the left.  Delete the first column below the (now two!) useful files.  Continue this a total of n-1 times, at which point all useful files are along the left-most column and simply delete all other columns.  The pictures shows the files (red are useful and green are deleted in each of 4 steps).

[image]

if the shift is column first vs row first, then only 2 steps

[image]

Comment: But the files after the first deletion won't look as in the picture .

Comment: This method seems to take only 2 deletes - one column and one rectangle.

Comment: I observed this right now . Thought is a lot harder than this...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is (a lot) easier than I thought .

Attach numbers to the positions : from $1$ to $n^2$ from left to right .

On the first column delete all the files except the first , which is useful (namely the files $n+1$ , $2n+1 , \ldots ,n^2-n+1$ )

Now take the useful file on the row $k$ namely $n(k-1)+k$ .

Exactly $k-1$ files will be deleted that are now on smaller positions than this file so after the operation this file will be on the position :

$$n(k-1)+k-(k-1)=n(k-1)+1$$

This means that all files will be on the first column and then we only need to delete the remaining rectangle and we're done .